# Is there a way to find $P(x \mid y \,\,\text{and}\,\, z)$ given $P(x \mid y)$ and $P(x \mid z)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

For example, if P(cavity | infrequent brushing) = 0.524 and P(cavity | toothache) = 0.662, is there a way to find P(cavity | infrequent brushing and toothache)?

Comment: Only if you know $P(y|z)$ or $P(z|y)$

Comment: @Henry Wrong. Even with that, P(x|y,z) is not uniquely determined.

Answer (score 2):

> In general, $P(x\mid y)$ and $P(x\mid z)$ do not determine $P(x\mid y,z)$.

To see this, consider a partition of the sample space into three disjoint events $a$, $b$ and $c$ with common probability $1/3$.

- If $x=b$, $y=a\cup b$ and $z=b\cup c$, then $P(x\mid y)=P(x\mid z)=1/2$ and $P(x\mid y,z)=1$.
- If $x=a\cup c$, $y=a\cup b$ and $z=b\cup c$, then $P(x\mid y)=P(x\mid z)=1/2$ and $P(x\mid y,z)=0$.

The values of $P(x\mid y)$ and $P(x\mid z)$ are both at $1/2$ only for the clarity of the exposition. These values have nothing specific and similar counterexamples hold for other values.

Note finally that $P(y\mid z)=P(z\mid y)=1/2$ in both cases hence $P(x\mid y)$, $P(x\mid z)$, $P(y\mid z)$ and $P(z\mid y)$ do not determine $P(x\mid y,z)$ either.